# Android Spinner not updating with newly Selected item Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-spinner

I have a spinner containing a list of countries. The page load with the following

[image]

The user select a country from the drop down menu. Let say we select Algeria

[image]

After Algeria is selected the drop down will close but the selected country is still shown as Unknown

[image]

Next, when I select another country, only then the previous country which was Algeria is shown. Not the newly selected country.

[image]

My code

```
public class SpinnerActivity : Activity
{
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private Spinner spinner;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "Main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SpinnerControl);

        spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
        spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
            this, Resource.Array.countries_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

        adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        spinner.Adapter = adapter;

        spinner.SetSelection(GameSettings.ISettings.CountrySetting);
    }


    private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        spinner.SetSelection(adapter.GetPosition(e.Position));
        Console.WriteLine("Setting{0}", GameSettings.ISettings.CountrySetting);
        if (e.Position != GameSettings.ISettings.CountrySetting)
        {
            GameSettings.ISettings.CountrySetting = e.Position;
            Options.countryText.ChangeText("Country: " + System.Environment.NewLine + ScoreHelper.GetCountry(GameSettings.ISettings.CountrySetting));
            ScoreBoards.Board.IsInfoUpdated = true;

        }
    }
}
```

So how do I update the spinner with the selected item right away when the drop down is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this issue only happens on device emulator. I did not encounter it when debugging on a physical device.